# AbstractMethodError on org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

With the following code:

```
private Document transformDoc(Source source) throws TransformerException, IOException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);

    Transformer xslTransformer =
            factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(pdfTransformXslt.getInputStream()));
    JDOMResult result = new JDOMResult();
    xslTransformer.transform(source, result);
    return result.getDocument();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

Why is this?

Here's my Maven dependency tree:

```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Building mc-hub-batch
      task-segment: [dependency:tree]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   snapshot com.billmelater:mc-test-support:2.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from repository.jboss.org
   [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
   com.billmelater:mc-hub-batch:jar:2.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
   +- com.billmelater:mc-hub-core:jar:2.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT:compile
   |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
   |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
   |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
   |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
   |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.4; omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   +- com.billmelater:mc-test-support:jar:2.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT:test
   |  +- (com.billmelater:mc-hub-core:jar:2.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.5.6.SEC01:test
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6.SEC01:test - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6.SEC01:test - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC01:test - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6.SEC01:test - omitted for conflict with 2.5.6)
   |  +- (org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.5:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.5.8; scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam:jar:2.2.0.GA:test
   |  |  +- xstream:xstream:jar:1.1.3:test
   |  |  +- (xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- org.jboss.el:jboss-el:jar:1.0_02.CR4:test
   |  +- (org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.8:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:test - version managed from 3.3.0.SP1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:test
   |  |  +- (org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:test - version managed from 3.3.0.SP1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:test - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-jboss:test - version managed from 1.6.1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:test
   |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.1.0.GA:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14:test - omitted for duplicate)
   +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
   +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
   |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4:compile
   |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
   |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
   |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.0:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.6:compile
   |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
   |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
   |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6:compile
   |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
   |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
   +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
   |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
   +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
   |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.6)
   |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-jboss:compile (version managed from 1.6.1)
   |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile (version managed from 1.1)
   |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
   |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile - version managed from 3.3.0.SP1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
   |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
   |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
   |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile - version managed from 3.3.0.SP1; omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-jboss:compile - version managed from 1.6.1; omitted for duplicate)
   +- ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14:compile
   +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
   +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
   |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
   +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
   |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
   +- org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.8:test
   +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.5:test
   |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test (version managed from 3.8.2)
   |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:test - version managed from 1.4.2; omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test - omitted for duplicate)
   +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:test
   +- jboss:javassist:jar:3.3.ga:provided
   +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
   +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:provided
   +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:0.95:compile
   |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for cycle)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for cycle)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for cycle)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
   |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for cycle)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.7:compile
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
   |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
   |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.1:compile
   |  \- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
   +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.3.1:compile
   |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.4; omitted for duplicate)
   +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.0:test
   \- org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:2.2:test
      +- (org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.2:test - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
      \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:test (version managed from 2.1_3)
```

Can anyone tell me how to clear out intellij's classpath too?

Here's the classpath (from within intellij)

```
/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%208.1.4.app/plugins/testng/lib/testng-jdk15.jar
/Users/jbristow/Library/Application%20Support/IntelliJIDEA80/clover-idea-2.6.3.2.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/deploy.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/dt.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/jce.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/plugin.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/charsets.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/classes.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/dt.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jce.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jconsole.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jsse.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/laf.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/ui.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/apple_provider.jar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
/opt/bml_code/mc/mc-hub-batch/target/test-classes/
/opt/bml_code/mc/mc-hub-batch/target/classes/ /opt/bml_code/mc/mc-hub-core/target/test-classes/
/opt/bml_code/mc/mc-hub-core/target/classes/
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.2_08/jsf-api-1.2_08.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/faces/jsf-impl/1.2_08/jsf-impl-1.2_08.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.0/commons-digester-2.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/xml/soap/saaj-api/1.3/saaj-api-1.3.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-validator-3.1.0.GA.jar /Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-jboss/dom4j-1.6.1-jboss.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/jboss/seam/jboss-seam/2.2.0.GA/jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xstream/xstream/1.1.3/xstream-1.1.3.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.3.4.O/xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar /Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/jboss/el/jboss-el/1.0_02.CR4/jboss-el-1.0_02.CR4.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/5.8/testng-5.8-jdk15.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/groboutils/groboutils-core/5/groboutils-core-5.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/unitils/unitils/2.2/unitils-2.2.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.2.2/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.3/commons-pool-1.3.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/2.6.9/ognl-2.6.9.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.2.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-search/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-search-3.1.0.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/2.3.0/lucene-core-2.3.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javax/ejb/ejb-api/3.0/ejb-api-3.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-batch-infrastructure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/2.5.6/spring-core-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/stax/stax/1.2.0/stax-1.2.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.5.4/aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.5.4/aspectjweaver-1.5.4.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3/xstream-1.3.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.0/jettison-1.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/2.5.6/spring-aop-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/2.5.6/spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/2.5.6/spring-context-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/2.5.6/spring-tx-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/dbunit/dbunit/2.4.5/dbunit-2.4.5.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.7/junit-4.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
/opt/bml_code/mc/mc-test-support/target/test-classes/
/opt/bml_code/mc/mc-test-support/target/classes/
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/2.5.6.SEC01/spring-core-2.5.6.SEC01.jar /Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/2.5.6.SEC01/spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC01.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/2.5.6.SEC01/spring-context-2.5.6.SEC01.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/2.5.6.SEC01/spring-tx-2.5.6.SEC01.jar /Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/2.5.6.SEC01/spring-jdbc-2.5.6.SEC01.jar /Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.4.GA/javassist-3.4.GA.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.2/velocity-1.6.2.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/ojdbc/ojdbc/14/ojdbc-14.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.7/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/jboss/javassist/3.3.ga/javassist-3.3.ga.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1/jaxen-1.1.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/0.95/fop-0.95.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/1.3.1/xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.1/commons-io-1.3.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svg-dom/1.7/batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-anim/1.7/batik-anim-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-awt-util/1.7/batik-awt-util-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-util/1.7/batik-util-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-dom/1.7/batik-dom-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-css/1.7/batik-css-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-ext/1.7/batik-ext-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis-ext/1.3.04/xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-xml/1.7/batik-xml-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.6.0/xalan-2.6.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-parser/1.7/batik-parser-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-bridge/1.7/batik-bridge-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-gvt/1.7/batik-gvt-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-script/1.7/batik-script-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-transcoder/1.7/batik-transcoder-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svggen/1.7/batik-svggen-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-extension/1.7/batik-extension-1.7.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.3.1/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/easymock/easymock/2.0/easymock-2.0.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/org/easymock/easymockclassextension/2.2/easymockclassextension-2.2.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
/Users/jbristow/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%208.1.4.app/lib/idea_rt.jar
```

Comment: Looks like java versions conflict.
Could you please provide info about classpath used and version of java?

Comment: @JBristow: clean your build and compile your project from scratch - do you get any compile time errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [java.lang.AbstractMethodError](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

This means that an abstract method which is declared in the API in the current classpath lacks in the concrete implementation in the current classpath.

> org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

This is introduced since [Java SE 5.0](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). Thus, this exception suggests that the API in the current classpath is at least Java SE 5.0 and the concrete implementation is incompatible with that.

Xalan 2.7.0 was the first version to implement it. Thus, you've an older-versioned Xalan version somewhere in the classpath.

If you cannot seem to locate it in the forest called classpath, I'd suggest to scan the disk file system locations which are covered by the classpath with a search tool which can search inside ZIP (JAR) files. I myself use [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) for this. Just associate the tool with JAR files and search for files matching filename `TransformerFactoryImpl.class` (if necessary including the path which represents the package). The results should contain information about the JAR file where it is found in.

Comment: A transitive dependency was loading 2.6, so I excluded it and explicity included 2.7.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue recently and resolved by removing unnecessary xalan jar from the classpath. As the parser implementation required was present in rt.jar but as xalan jar was present, it was referring that and giving me this issue. So one solution can be tried is to remove xalan or Xerces Jar and check.